# How can I tell which assembly in my installer is not 64-bit?

Tags: c#, 32bit-64bit

I am trying to install a windows service written in c#/ VS2010, which uses a number of libraries I wrote.  I am developing on a 32-bit machine, but I am deploying to a 64-bit machine.  I keep getting the BadImageFormatException during the install process, telling me one of my assemblies (or a dependency) is not loadable.  I have scoured my solution looking for non-64-bit assemblies, and I cannot find any.  How can I find the guilty party?

Comment: Right-click your service project, Properties, Build tab.  Change Platform Target to x86.

Comment: Are you getting the error on the developer machine or on the deployment machine? Since you just wrote "during the install" but not where ;)

Comment: on the deployment machine, in the middle of the installation; it rolls back the installation.

Comment: Probably a dependency of a dependency.  That's how it usually ends up.  Grab you some process monitor from technet and look at all the files your application tries to load.

Comment: @HansPassant, that won't do.  I am using 64 bit frameworks on the 64-bit machine that do not play nice with 32 bit assemblies; besides, why would anyone build 32 bit assemblies for a 64 bit machine unless there was absolutely no other choice?  I'm not looking for a workaround, I'm looking for a solution.

Comment: Why do you explicitly set targeting platform? By default, your libraries should run both on 32-bit and 64-bit platforms.

Comment: @ArifMertAkçakaya, yes, MY libraries could run on both; unfortunately I am interfacing with third party libraries that are strictly 32 or 64 bit (i.e., Crystal Reports).  I have the proper libraries installed on both machines, but it chokes with a 32-bit assembly on my 64 bit machine.

Comment: @Will, can you give me an idea what to filter on?  Process monitor creates a haystack around the needle.

Comment: If the msi rolls back it sjouldn't be wrong on the files you install, since they could be anything, ie textfiles. What CustomActions are you running? One of them are probably in the wrong format. Btw, AFAIK windows installer always runs in 32bit-mode, so CA's should be compiled for 32bit.

Comment: @MattiasÅslund, I am only doing the service install custom actions.  I am sure this is where the error is triggered; it is also not something I can dispense with, as the whole point is to install and register the service.  Whether or not the installer is 32 bit is not an issue; the application it is installing can be 32 bit or 64.

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs: Whatever application is going kablooey.  That's the one you filter on.  You'll see everything it does, right up until the point it crashes.  Also, since you're having the issue with the installer, have you turned on MSI logging?  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/223300 at least that will help narrow down your problem.

Comment: @Will, it's a well-trapped exception, it seems.  I see nothing on the process monitor.

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs: MSI logging?  Also, you might want to concentrate on the last thing loaded before it fails... Anyhow, those are my hints on figuring this out.  Other than that, I have no idea.  Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After more hours of frustration and the lack of an answer, I decided to rewrite the service as a console app.  It installs, it works.  Even if it is a bit ghetto.